# Selenium RC htmlSuite error with IE https app

Tags: selenium-rc

I am trying to use Selenium RC but i keep getting this error whenever i start the server.
"HTML suite exception seen:
java.lang.RuntimeException: sessionId 7643 doesn't exist; perhaps this session w
as already stopped?"

The command I use is

java -jar C:\selenium-remote-control-1.0.3\selenium-server-1.0.3\selenium-server.jar -multiwindow -htmlSuite "*iexplore" "https://user1.apps.com/" "C:\TEMP\Selenium Tests\TestSuite1.html" "C:\TEMP\Selenium Tests\results.html"

However with the same command if I change *iexplore to *firefox then it works.

I need to run the test with IE, please help!Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal solution, but this worked for me:

1. Open IE & go to Tools > Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings.
2. Check the box *'Use a proxy server for your LAN'*
3. For address put '*localhost*', for port put '*4444*'

Rather than using `"*iexplore"` use:

`"*custom C:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe`

This should work OK to launch IE. (Obviously the above path should reflect wherever **iexplore.exe** is located on your computer.)

The downside of this method is that you will need to turn this proxy off each time you want to use IE without Selenium, but it's not bad as a quick hack.

If I come across something better I'll put it up, but still learning myself for now! =)

All the best,

Dave

Comment: Thanks Dave. This works!

However I'm now having anther problem: After launch IE by using *custom, I gor "Permission Denied" error when cross differnet domain, for example in our application clicking a button will go from a page on https://domain1 to a page on https://domain2, on the page of https://domain2 when I enter a value, I got the "Permission Denied" error. I have read on the internet that use *iexplore would solve the problem, however *iexplore doesn't work for me.

Is there any way to solve the "Permission Denied" problem when use *custom to launch IE?

Many thanks!!